# Как изменить системную громкость в Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows-10

Пожалуйста подскажите библиотеку и команду для изменения системной громкости win10 python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот простейший способ. Устанавливаете `pynput` в командной строке:

```
pip install pynput
```

Используете такой код:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key,Controller
keyboard = Controller()
```

Для увеличения громкости на `2` используйте следующую команду:

```
keyboard.press(Key.media_volume_up)
```

А для уменьшения на 2 - эту:

```
keyboard.press(Key.media_volume_down)
```

То есть мы управляем звуком *нажатием* клавиш:)

---

**P.S. Надеюсь, это будет использовано в благих познавательных целях**